# I keep on losing what's in my Java workspace, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

Every now and then when i open up my eclipse i notice in my Package Explorer all my projects are gone, there still in the Workspace folder but they don't appear in my Package Explorer, to get them back i need to create a new File and name it top to whatever the original file was called. Is there any way to prevent it because it can become a nuisance.

Comment: Have you tried import project?

Comment: A hack : Do not close the eclipse. Try to kill the eclipse exe from task manager that's what I do always. 
One more suggestion, you can try new version of eclipse.

Comment: replace your eclipse with new one.

Comment: what is the eclipse version

Comment: Thilina Rubasingha How would i check that? (Do u mean the name or actual number If name it's Luna)

Comment: Thilina Rubasingha I'm updating it to Mars i'll let you know if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases this is caused by workspace meta data getting corrupted. It can happen due to many reasons like unexpected computer restart, eclipse being ended forcefully by the OS etc . Once the  meta data gets corrupted the problem may keep recurring.

There are different things you could try.

First backup all your work,your projects and even your workspace before your try anything. None of the fixes actually require this but it is better to be safe than sorry.

**Workaround 1 :**

Go to the drop-down menu in Project Explorer and select Top Level Elements -> Projects.

**Workaround 2**

File->Import->General->From Existing Project.

If you do not see any projects make sure to look in the root folder of your workspace.

You could import projects one by one or select all projects at once . 
If the project are grayed out , try refresh button near select all button.

In most cases this should fix the issue. If it keeps recurring try below fix.

**Fix 1 :**

Close Eclipse.

cd /home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins 
(directory path may be different for different OS/eclipse installation)

rm -rf org.eclipse.core.resources (remove the file)

Start Eclipse

Do File->Import

General->Existing Projects into Workspace

Click the "Select root directory" field and browse to each subfolder in your workspace folder, and import.

**Fix 2 :**

Update your eclipse to latest version.

**Fix 3**

If the issue keeps recurring even after all these steps, then install latest version of eclipse to a different folder.

Create a new workspace.

Backup all your project to an archive file from old eclipse installation.

Import all your projects into the new workspace from new eclipse installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have other workspace too, but you can always switch between workspace.

In Eclipse, under File, There is a option called Switch Workspace. You might also need to right click at the Package Explore then hit refresh (or <kbd>F5</kbd> will also do it)
[image]